# Unresolved Reference R when I when I create an action between two fragments in the navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to go from one fragment to another and when I create the action in the navigation component when executing I get an error Unresolved Reference R

I don't understand why it doesn't work, I've tried everything to delete the fragments and recreate them but nothing works. If I remove the action everything runs perfectly

Comment: It would be easiest if you posted your Fragment's code (the one you're trying to use the action in), including your imports at the top

Answer (score 0):

You copied and pasted code from another project? Somethings it gets trouble about the R. Android Studio doesn't give you suggestions? Probably you only need to import proper package.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
import packagename.R
```

at the top of the file, and reimport it by pressing alt+enter while focused at place where R is used (eg. R.string.stringname).